# How to order test cases using priority and groups annotation?

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, testng

there are some flows that i want to test through automation. i am using selenium , maven, java and testNG. i have 2 different class. Let say class A and Class B.

```
 public class A (){
    @Test(groups="flow1",priority=0)
    public void method a1()
    {
    }
    @Test(groups="flow1".priority=2)
    public void method a2()
    {
    }
    @Test
    public void method a3()
    {
    }
```

and 2nd class is class B

```
 public class b (){
    @Test(groups="flow1", priority=1)
    public void method b1()
    {
    }
    @Test
    public void method b2()
    {
    }
    @Test
    public void method b3()
    {
    }
```

now i want to achieve flow like below

```
method a1()
method b1()
method a2()
```

i had try in this way through testng.xml

```
 <test name="test1">
    <groups>
    <run>
    <include name="flow1" />
    </run>
    </groups>
    <classes>
    <class name="a" />
    <class name="b" />
    </classes>
    </test>
```

but i am not getting that output. it will run only one test cases and then it is skipping others.
i had try also some different way but i am not getting my goal.
can anybody help me

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I control the order of execution of tests in Maven?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12075725/how-do-i-control-the-order-of-execution-of-tests-in-maven)

Comment: @Smajl i want to achieve it using testNG annotations using groups and priority. and also there is no parameter in that satisfy my situation.

Comment: I think that this cannot be done using maven. The only thing that comes close to what you are trying to do is using Surefire plugin and the workaround in that SO answer.

Comment: but it will run test cases alphabetical order. and my test cases name are not in alphabetical order. is there any way to do

Comment: I don't think that there is a way how to do that, but I would be quite curious if I am wrong. Anyway, it is not a good practice to have dependent tests. The ordering should generally not matter.

Comment: what result do you get?

Comment: @Smajl yes i know that it is not good practice but i don't have any choice in that so in any way i have to do that

Comment: @peetya it will executing only first test after the first test all test cases are skipped.

Comment: If you need to run the tests (integration tests) in a particular order you should define the dependencies in the tests `@Test(dependsOn=...`) otherwise it's not really defined..you can use things like ordering by filename etc. which can be configured in Maven-Surefire/Failsafe (better for integration tests) etc.

Comment: It looks like an issue, could you create a new one? https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues

Answer (score 0):

in your testng.xml just add group-by-instances="true"

```
<suite thread-count="2" verbose="10" name="testSuite" parallel="tests">
<test verbose="2" name="MytestCase" group-by-instances="true">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.A.classA" />
        <class name="com.A.classB" />
    </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```