# How to run forked JUnit tests in optimal order?

Tags: maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

I have some long running JUnit tests which I want to run first to avoid them being queued and executed last and thus delaying the whole test execution process.

I currently use maven surefire to run my tests using:

- `forkCount`: 5
- `reuseForks`: false

Is there a way to specify which tests should be run first? Or a way to optimize the order in which the tests are run?

The `runOrder=balanced` parameter does not seem to work in combination with forkCount > 0  and reuseForks false.

Comment: A specific order needed for unit tests shows that you don't have unit tests which are by definition wrong...Those tests are integration tests which should be done by TestNG and maven-failsafe-plugin instead...

Comment: Don't get confused by the initial title. I want to run the unit tests in the optimal order to save execution time. I updated the title.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can’t determine the test execution order. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12075725/how-do-i-control-the-order-of-execution-of-tests-in-maven) is a clumsy workaround for this problem. For integration tests, I use a [JUnit extension](http://scg.unibe.ch/research/jexample) to run tests in specific order.

Comment: For integration tests I would always use TestNG instead of JUnit cause TestNG has dependencies which is needed sometimes in integration tests...