# Running tests in Maven in specific order

Tags: java, maven, groovy

I am struggling to run my groovy-spock tests in specific order.  Currently, I can run all my tests but it does not follow any sequence.  I read about  [http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html][1] but I did not find anything about following a specific order.  Can we do this using Maven?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693626/how-to-run-test-methods-in-specific-order-in-junit4

Comment: Did you try `runOrder` argument? Check details here for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12075725/how-do-i-control-the-order-of-execution-of-tests-in-maven

Comment: It is a really bad idea, to have tests depend on each other. And otherwise, there is no reason for a certain order.

Comment: In Spock there is an annotation `@Stepwise` but usually unit tests should never rely on a particular order otherwise you are doing integration tests...