# REST-Assured fail tests when there is a delay

Tags: java, rest, testing, junit, rest-assured

I've built a RESTful API in Java using JaxRS/Jersey to test several services/databases offered on IBM Cloud.

To test the API, I'm using REST-Assured and created ~15 tests. I use Maven to spin up a Jetty server, run the tests with the failsafe plugin, then close the server.

Everything is fine until it gets to an endpoint that has any sort of delay in it such as a Thread.sleep or anything that creates a new Thread. This is the pattern I am witnessing. The endpoint fails ~80% of the time.

Does anyone know why having a Thread.sleep or new Thread in the logic causes this behavior and if so, any way to get around this other than ignoring the test?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi! 
It would be helpful if you could give us some more specifics around how the tests fail exactly: 
Are there any exceptions or specific reasons for why the test is failing? Does the test fail immediately or after a very long time (say 30 seconds)?

Comment: Hi Matthias! It seems like the test fails by outputting a 404 instead of an expected 200 about 80% of the time. However, all the tests that run after that specific failure fail immediately without a status code at all. So I think that the sleep or new Thread is causing some unusual behavior. 

When I comment out the specific tests that I know fails, everything else runs fine.

Comment: Hi! If the test fails - what is the reason for it to fail? an assertion failing, or an exception?

Comment: Actually, after uncommenting out the tests and running the tests again, the specified test itself doesn't fail but some tests that run after them fail from assertion. However, when i use mvn clean install | grep -v WARNING, the tests pass 100% of the time from what I've tried so far. There are quite a bit of warning statements when the build runs. Do you think this affects the tests itself?

Comment: I am not too sure about the warning themselves. I would think it is rather unrelated. 

My only suspicion at the moment might be around the _order_ of tests being executed. I've had a situation in which a field in a class was accidentally static. Two tests were accessing that field. They would pass if executed in one order, but fail if executed in the other. 
I am trying to find some clue on what is happening. Do you think it is possible to share the actual build output (e.g. a link to pastebin or something)?

Comment: Do you know how to specify the order functions within a test should run in? I've tried @FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING) before to run specific functions within a test in order but that didn't seem to work.... Also, do you know how to specify the order that the actual test files (e.g. Test1.java, Test2.java...) should run in? I'm suspecting the latter has something to do with configurations in Maven.

Comment: configuring the order in maven - check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12075725/how-do-i-control-the-order-of-execution-of-tests-in-maven

Comment: however it is important to note: if there is something about the order of your tests, it is even more critical to investigate the issue. this could very likely be a severe bug in your application that only gets exposed randomly and is never reproducable.

Back then when I had such an issue, it was actually a field in a form method that was static by accident. that caused a specific value of the form submission to be overridden by other people who submitted the form at the same time. (imagine it being your credit card number being used for someone else's purchase)

Comment: I'll look over my code again. Thanks for all your help Matthias!